# What is wrong with my main method?

Tags: java

I am a java noob. I keep getting errors in the main method. Please help! I think I'm not calling the methods the right way. Everything else should be working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputName(kbd);
        inputIncome(kbd);
        inputMarried(kbd);
        calculateThreshold();
        incomeBelowThreshold();
        incomeAboveThreshold();
        taxBelowThreshold();
        taxAboveThreshold();
        totalTaxes();
        displayResults();

    }

    public static String inputName (Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        String name = kbd.nextLine();
        return name;
    }

    public static double inputIncome (Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.print("What is your annual income?");
        double userIncome = kbd.nextDouble();
        return userIncome;
    }

    public static char inputMarried (Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.print("Are you married? (y for yes, n for no)");
        char married = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        return married;
    }

    public static double calculateThreshold (char married) {
        double incomeThreshold;
        if (married == 'y') {
            incomeThreshold = 80000;
        } else {
            incomeThreshold = 40000;
        } 
        return incomeThreshold;
    }

    public static double incomeBelowThreshold (double userIncome , double incomeThreshold) {
        double incomeBelowThreshold;
        if (userIncome <= incomeThreshold) {
        incomeBelowThreshold = incomeThreshold - userIncome;
        } else {
            incomeBelowThreshold = userIncome;
        }
        return incomeBelowThreshold;
    }

    public static double incomeAboveThreshold (double userIncome, double incomeThreshold) {
        double incomeAboveThreshold;
        if (userIncome >= incomeThreshold) {
            incomeAboveThreshold = incomeThreshold - userIncome;
        } else {
            incomeAboveThreshold = 0;
        }
        return incomeAboveThreshold;
    }

    public static double taxBelowThreshold (double incomeBelowThreshold) {
        double taxBelowThreshold;
        taxBelowThreshold = incomeBelowThreshold * .25;
        return taxBelowThreshold;
    }

    public static double taxAboveThreshold (double incomeAboveThreshold) {
        double taxAboveThreshold;
        taxAboveThreshold = incomeAboveThreshold *.35;
        return taxAboveThreshold;
    }

    public static double totalTaxes (double taxBelowThreshold, double taxAboveThreshold) {
        double totalTaxes;
        totalTaxes = taxBelowThreshold + taxAboveThreshold;
        return totalTaxes;
    }

    public static void displayResults (String Name, char married, double income, double totalTaxes) {
        System.out.print("Name:" + Name);
        String marriedStatus;
        if (married == 'y') {
            marriedStatus = "Married";
        } else {
            marriedStatus = "Single";
        }
        System.out.print("Marital Status:" + marriedStatus);
        System.out.printf("Income: %.2f" + income);
        System.out.printf("Taxes: %.2f" + totalTaxes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the error you are getting in your main.

Comment: Give us a clue: what errors are you getting?

Comment: hard to help you / your question hazy / what's the error? / share it may be

Comment: You're losing all computed values from these methods. If you return a value from one method, and require it in another, you should assign it to a variable and pass it to the other method. Ex, 'char c = inputMarried(kbd); calculateThreshold(c);'

Comment: The method calculate threshold(char) in the type Assignment 5 is not applicable for the arguments (). It shows that for all of them through calculateThreshold to displayresults.

Comment: -1 ALWAYS copy/paste the exact error messages into your question, and, where possible, identify what lines in your code listing are identified by line numbers in the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANK YOU!!!!!!

`calculate threshold(char) in the type Assignment 5 is not applicable for the arguments ()`

In the future, please ALWAYS post as much information about the actual error as possible. Don't make everybody guess :)

In this case:

1) Save the return value of "married":

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        char married = inputMarried(kbd);
```

2) Then pass it to "calculateThreshold()".  Save the return value of "threshold() while you're at it:

```
    ...
    double threshold = calculateThreshold (married);
```

3) Be sure to do the same for the rest of your program.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like some of your methods are expecting arguments and you are not providing them.

For example

```
public static double calculateThreshold (char married){}
```

you cannot call this method `calculateThreshold();`

You need to pass in the char for married 
calculateThreshold ('y');

Comment: congratulations on your first 10 earned rep :)

Comment: Thanks, have to earn a certain rep for a class but it's actually fun, I think I'll continue doing this!

Answer (score 0):

One error is that you have methods that require a parameter, but you are not passing one.  `calculateThreshold()`, for instance, takes one parameter, and `incomeBelowThreshold()` takes two.  You are also not returning values from your input routines; this is not an error, but may be flagged as a warning (depending on how you're editing and compiling your stuff), but you're going to need the values from your input routines to pass to your other routines, possibly converting them beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all your methods return some answers in which it is suppose to deliver to the next method or so...

Your mistake is you are not assigning the returned values to a variable..so please correct it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputName(kbd);
        inputIncome(kbd);
        inputMarried(kbd);
        // modify this line calculateThreshold();
        calculateThreshold('a');
        // modify this line incomeBelowThreshold();
        incomeBelowThreshold(2.1, 2.2);
        // modify this line incomeAboveThreshold();
        incomeAboveThreshold(2.1, 2.2);
        // modify this line taxBelowThreshold();
        taxBelowThreshold(2.1);
        // modify this line taxAboveThreshold();
        taxAboveThreshold(2.1);
        // modify this line totalTaxes();
        totalTaxes(2.1, 2.1);
        // modify this line displayResults();
        displayResults("",'a', 2.1, 2.1);

    }
```